# How to deal with temporally and spatially consistent NaN values as an input to CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, nan, netcdf

I have a [data cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cube) as an [nc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF), with coordinates time, latitude and longitude. Imagine it is a daily temperature map of Europe for 10 years.

The problem I need to address is that the sea is masked and let’s say it has NaN values consistently in all data points in time in the corresponding to sea latitude and longitudes.

If I need to input this to a [convolutional neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) (CNN), like a video stream, how do I deal with these data points?
Filling them with some interpolation method or similar is not an option.